# java help, Total and Enter buttons in the class are not working, I tried to review the action listener for both buttons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, calculator

/** This java class works as sales simulator, I have difficulty working the Total and                   the enter buttons, the problem is with the Total and Enter buttons, I cannot figure why these buttons are not working!!
       */

// Import applications from Java library

```
        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.*;
        import javax.swing.*;
        import java.text.*;


    // Starting CashRegister class
    public class CashRegister extends JFrame
    {
    //initiate  value


       double subtotal = 0.0; // stores subtotal of items purchased

       // JLabel and JTextField to enter amount


      private JLabel amountJLabel;
       private JTextField amountJTextField;


       // JButtons to enter numbers in amountJTextField


       private JButton oneJButton;
       private JButton twoJButton;
       private JButton threeJButton;
       private JButton fourJButton;
       private JButton fiveJButton;
       private JButton sixJButton;
       private JButton sevenJButton;
       private JButton eightJButton;
       private JButton nineJButton;
       private JButton zeroJButton;
       private JButton pointJButton;

       // JButton to add value in amountJTextField to subtotal


       private JButton enterJButton;


       // JButton to determine tax and calculate final total


       private JButton totalJButton;

       // JButton to delete value displayed in amountJTextField


       private JButton deleteJButton;

       // JButton to clear results


       private JButton clearJButton;

       // JLabel and JTextField to display subtotal


       private JLabel subtotalJLabel;


       private JTextField subtotalJTextField;

       // JLabel and JTextField to display tax


       private JLabel taxJLabel;
       private JTextField taxJTextField;

       // JLabel and JTextField to display final total


       private JLabel totalJLabel;
       private JTextField totalJTextField;

       // DecimalFormat to format dollar amounts


       private DecimalFormat dollars = new DecimalFormat( "$0.00" );


       // no-argument constructor
       public CashRegister()
       {
          createUserInterface();
       }

       // create and position GUI components; register event handlers


       private void createUserInterface()
       {
          // get content pane for attaching GUI components


          Container contentPane = getContentPane();

          // enable explicit positioning of GUI components

          contentPane.setLayout( null );

          // set up amountJLabel


          amountJLabel = new JLabel();
          amountJLabel.setBounds( 20, 20, 15, 20 );
          amountJLabel.setText( "$" );
          contentPane.add( amountJLabel );

          // set up amountJTextField


          amountJTextField = new JTextField();
          amountJTextField.setBounds( 40, 20, 260, 20 );
          contentPane.add( amountJTextField );

          // set up oneJButton


          oneJButton = new JButton();
          oneJButton.setBounds( 55, 70, 45, 20 );
          oneJButton.setText( "1" );
          contentPane.add( oneJButton );
          oneJButton.addActionListener(

             new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class


           {
                // event handler called when oneJButton is pressed


                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                {
                   oneJButtonActionPerformed( event );
                }

             }

          // end anonymous inner class

          ); 

          // end call to addActionListener

          // set up twoJButton


          twoJButton = new JButton();
          twoJButton.setBounds( 100, 70, 45, 20 );
          twoJButton.setText( "2" );
          contentPane.add( twoJButton );
          twoJButton.addActionListener(

             new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class
             {
                // event handler called when twoJButton is pressed


           public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                {
                   twoJButtonActionPerformed( event );
                }

             } 

          // end anonymous inner class

          ); 

    // end call to addActionListener

          // set up threeJButton


          threeJButton = new JButton();
          threeJButton.setBounds( 145, 70, 45, 20 );
          threeJButton.setText( "3" );
          contentPane.add( threeJButton );
          threeJButton.addActionListener(

             new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class
             {
                // event handler called when threeJButton is pressed


                  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                {
                   threeJButtonActionPerformed( event );
                }

             } 

    // end anonymous inner class

          ); 

    // end call to addActionListener

          // set up fourJButton


       fourJButton = new JButton();
          fourJButton.setBounds( 55, 90, 45, 20 );
          fourJButton.setText( "4" );
          contentPane.add( fourJButton );
          fourJButton.addActionListener(

             new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class
             {
                // event handler called when fourJButton is pressed


    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                {
                   fourJButtonActionPerformed( event );
                }

             } 

    // end anonymous inner class

          );

     // end call to addActionListener

          // set up fiveJButton


    fiveJButton = new JButton();
          fiveJButton.setBounds( 100, 90, 45, 20 );
          fiveJButton.setText( "5" );
          contentPane.add( fiveJButton );
          fiveJButton.addActionListener(

             new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class
             {
                // event handler called when fiveJButton is pressed


             public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                {
                   fiveJButtonActionPerformed( event );
                }

             }

     // end anonymous inner class

          ); 

    // end call to addActionListener

          // set up sixJButton


    sixJButton = new JButton();
          sixJButton.setBounds( 145, 90, 45, 20 );
          sixJButton.setText( "6" );
          contentPane.add( sixJButton );
          sixJButton.addActionListener(

             new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class
             {
                // event handler called when sixJButton is pressed


    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                {
                   sixJButtonActionPerformed( event );
                }

             }

     // end anonymous inner class

          ); 

    // end call to addActionListener

          // set up sevenJButton


       sevenJButton = new JButton();
          sevenJButton.setBounds( 55, 110, 45, 20 );
          sevenJButton.setText( "7" );
          contentPane.add( sevenJButton );
          sevenJButton.addActionListener(

             new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class
             {
                // event handler called when sevenJButton is pressed


        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                {
                   sevenJButtonActionPerformed( event );
                }

             } 

    // end anonymous inner class

          ); 

    // end call to addActionListener

          // set up eightJButton


       eightJButton = new JButton();
          eightJButton.setBounds( 100, 110, 45, 20 );
          eightJButton.setText( "8" );
          contentPane.add( eightJButton );
          eightJButton.addActionListener(

             new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class
             {
                // event handler called when eightJButton is pressed
                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                {
                   eightJButtonActionPerformed( event );
                }

             } // end anonymous inner class

          );

                // end call to addActionListener

                  // set up nineJButton


    nineJButton = new JButton();
          nineJButton.setBounds( 145, 110, 45, 20 );
          nineJButton.setText( "9" );
          contentPane.add( nineJButton );
          nineJButton.addActionListener(

             new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class
             {
                // event handler called when nineJButton is pressed


    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                {
                   nineJButtonActionPerformed( event );
                }

             } 

    // end anonymous inner class

          ); // end call to addActionListener

          // set up zeroJButton
          zeroJButton = new JButton();
          zeroJButton.setBounds( 100, 130, 45, 20 );
          zeroJButton.setText( "0" );
          contentPane.add( zeroJButton );
          zeroJButton.addActionListener(

             new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class
             {
                // event handler called when zeroJButton is pressed
                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                {
                   zeroJButtonActionPerformed( event );
                }

             }


              // end anonymous inner class

          ); 


           // end call to addActionListener

          // set up pointJButton


     pointJButton = new JButton();
          pointJButton.setBounds( 145, 130, 45, 20 );
          pointJButton.setText( "." );
          contentPane.add( pointJButton );
          pointJButton.addActionListener(

             new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class
             {
                // event handler called when pointJButton is pressed
                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                {
                   pointJButtonActionPerformed( event );
                }

             } 

    // end anonymous inner class

          ); 

    // end call to addActionListener

          // set up enterJButton


      enterJButton = new JButton();
          enterJButton.setBounds( 205, 70, 70, 20 );
          enterJButton.setText( "Enter" );
          contentPane.add( enterJButton );
          enterJButton.addActionListener(

             new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class
             {
                // event handler called when enterJButton is pressed
                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                {
                   enterJButtonActionPerformed( event );
                }

             } // end anonymous inner class

          ); 

    // end call to addActionListener

          // set up totalJButton


     totalJButton = new JButton();
          totalJButton.setBounds( 205, 90, 70, 20 );
          totalJButton.setText( "Total" );
          contentPane.add( totalJButton );
          totalJButton.addActionListener(

             new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class
             {
                // event handler called when totalJButton is pressed


     public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                {
                   totalJButtonActionPerformed( event );
                }

             } 

    // end anonymous inner class

          ); 

    // end call to addActionListener

          // set up deleteJButton


    deleteJButton = new JButton();
          deleteJButton.setBounds( 205, 110, 70, 20 );
          deleteJButton.setText( "Delete" );
          contentPane.add( deleteJButton );
          deleteJButton.addActionListener(

             new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class
             {
                // event handler called when deleteJButton is pressed


     public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                {
                   deleteJButtonActionPerformed( event );
                }

             } 

    // end anonymous inner class

          ); 

    // end call to addActionListener

          // set up clearJButton


    clearJButton = new JButton();
          clearJButton.setBounds( 205, 130, 70, 20 );
          clearJButton.setText( "Clear" );
          contentPane.add( clearJButton );
          clearJButton.addActionListener(

             new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class
             {
                // event handler called when clearJButton is pressed


     public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                {
                   clearJButtonActionPerformed( event );
                }

             } 

    // end anonymous inner class

          ); 

    // end call to addActionListener

          // set up subtotalJLabel;


      subtotalJLabel = new JLabel();
          subtotalJLabel.setBounds( 20, 180, 90, 20 );
          subtotalJLabel.setText( "Subtotal:" );
          contentPane.add( subtotalJLabel );

          // set up subtotalJTextField


    subtotalJTextField = new JTextField();
          subtotalJTextField.setBounds( 160, 180, 140, 20 );
          subtotalJTextField.setHorizontalAlignment( JTextField.RIGHT );
          subtotalJTextField.setEditable( false );
          subtotalJTextField.setText( "$0.00" );
          contentPane.add( subtotalJTextField );

          // set up taxJLabel
          taxJLabel = new JLabel();
          taxJLabel.setBounds( 20, 220, 60, 20 );
          taxJLabel.setText( "Tax:" );
          contentPane.add( taxJLabel );

          // set up taxJTextField


      taxJTextField = new JTextField();
          taxJTextField.setBounds( 160, 220, 140, 20 );
          taxJTextField.setHorizontalAlignment( JTextField.RIGHT );
          taxJTextField.setEditable( false );
          taxJTextField.setText( "$0.00" );
          contentPane.add( taxJTextField );

          // set up totalJLabel


    totalJLabel = new JLabel();
          totalJLabel.setBounds( 20, 260, 70, 20 );
          totalJLabel.setText( "Total:" );
          contentPane.add( totalJLabel );

          // set up totalJTextField


      totalJTextField = new JTextField();
          totalJTextField.setBounds( 160, 260, 140, 20 );
          totalJTextField.setHorizontalAlignment( JTextField.RIGHT );
          totalJTextField.setEditable( false );
          totalJTextField.setText( "$0.00" );
          contentPane.add( totalJTextField );

          // set properties of application's window


      setTitle( "Cash Register" ); // set window title
          setSize( 345, 330 );         // set window size
          setVisible( true );          // display window

       } 

    // end method createUserInterface

       // append "0" to the amount in amountJTextField


    private void zeroJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
       {
          amountJTextField.setText( amountJTextField.getText() + "0" );

       } 

    // end method zeroJButtonActionPerformed

       // append "1" to the amount in amountJTextField


     private void oneJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
       {
          amountJTextField.setText( amountJTextField.getText() + "1" );

       }


     // end method oneJButtonActionPerformed


    // append "2" to the amount in amountJTextField


      private void twoJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
       {
          amountJTextField.setText( amountJTextField.getText() + "2" );

       } // end method twoJButtonActionPerformed

       // append "3" to the amount in amountJTextField


     private void threeJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
       {
          amountJTextField.setText( amountJTextField.getText() + "3" );

       } 

    // end method threeJButtonActionPerformed

       // append "4" to the amount in amountJTextField


     private void fourJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
       {
          amountJTextField.setText( amountJTextField.getText() + "4" );

       } 

    // end method fourJButtonActionPerformed

       // append "5" to the amount in amountJTextField


    private void fiveJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
       {
          amountJTextField.setText( amountJTextField.getText() + "5" );

       } // end method fiveJButtonActionPerformed

       // append "6" to the amount in amountJTextField
       private void sixJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
       {
          amountJTextField.setText( amountJTextField.getText() + "6" );

       } 

    // end method sixJButtonActionPerformed

       // append "7" to the amount in amountJTextField


      private void sevenJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
       {
          amountJTextField.setText( amountJTextField.getText() + "7" );

       } // end method sevenJButtonActionPerformed

       // append "8" to the amount in amountJTextField
       private void eightJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
       {
          amountJTextField.setText( amountJTextField.getText() + "8" );

       } // end method eightJButtonActionPerformed

       // append "9" to the amount in amountJTextField
       private void nineJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
       {
          amountJTextField.setText( amountJTextField.getText() + "9" );

       } 

    // end method nineJButtonActionPerformed

       // append "." to the amount in amountJTextField


    private void pointJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
       {
          amountJTextField.setText( amountJTextField.getText() + "." );

       } // end method pointJButtonActionPerformed

   // calculate and display subtotal

   private void enterJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
   {

   }

    // end method enterJButtonActionPerformed

   // calculate and display total after taxes


 private void totalJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
   {

   } 

// end method totalJButtonActionPerformed

   // clear current amount displayed in amountJTextField
   private void deleteJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
   {
      amountJTextField.setText( "" );

   } 

     // end method deleteJButtonActionPerformed

   // clear all results
   private void clearJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
   {
      amountJTextField.setText( "" );
      subtotalJTextField.setText( "$0.00" );
      taxJTextField.setText( "$0.00" );
      totalJTextField.setText( "$0.00" );
      subtotal = 0.0; // reset subtotal to 0.0

   } 

    // end method clearJButtonActionPerformed

   // main method
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      CashRegister application = new CashRegister();
      application.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

   } 

     // end method main

     }/** the end of the program*/
```

Comment: umm, the action listeners for both those buttons are empty

Comment: Thank you Reimesus, I have reviewed that before posting the quetion and I am looking for help to find these methods that I should include in my Action listeners.

Comment: @mKorbel What's with the cJava tag?

Comment: @hichris123 be sure that I don't know, did you :-),

Comment: It is just misspelling, I am sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most simple way to show an ActionListener.
If you understand the basics of this, you'll be able to fix your own code :)

```
package actionlistenerexample;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ActionListenerExample extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton button1;
JButton button2;

public ActionListenerExample(){
   setVisible(true);

   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   add(panel);

   button1 = new JButton("Button1");
   button1.addActionListener(this);
   button2 = new JButton("Button2");
   button2.addActionListener(this);

   panel.add(button1);
   panel.add(button2);
   pack();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   JFrame jf = new ActionListenerExample();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    if(event.getSource() == button1){
        System.out.println("Button1 clicked");
    }
    if(event.getSource() == button2){
        System.out.println("Button2 clicked");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not performing any action here,

```
             new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class
             {
                // event handler called when totalJButton is pressed

                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                {
                   totalJButtonActionPerformed( event );
                }

             }
```

Calls `totalJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )` method

```
              private void totalJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
              {

                   //write some code here to perform some action

              }
```